# swiftui drag and drop puzzle game

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, swiftui, gesture, ios14

I want create a puzzle game how on picture. I have a first picture it's empty view and second images it's a few piece. When I started implements I have a problem with logic Gesture. I have a struct where I drag picture and change position on screen for it, but I can't how I can tighten it if right location for pieces and if wrong stay on new location.
Below my part my code which i can move pieces on screen and try add check for location pieces.

```
struct PieceView: View {
    
    @GestureState var dragState = DragState.inactive
    @State var pieceState: CGSize = CGSize(width: -134.5, height: -252.0)
    @State var pieceState1: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 409.5, y: 298.5)
    @State var pieceSatte4: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 734.5, y: 441.5)
    
    // value for piece and random location on screen
    @State var items: [Puzzle] = [Puzzle(id: UUID(), index: 1, pieceName: "piece1", locationPiece: CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%1000),y:Int(arc4random()%1000)), geo: .zero),
                                  Puzzle(id: UUID(), index: 2, pieceName: "piece2", locationPiece: CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%1000),y:Int(arc4random()%1000)), geo: .zero),
                                  Puzzle(id: UUID(), index: 3, pieceName: "piece3", locationPiece: CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%1000),y:Int(arc4random()%1000)), geo: .zero),
                                  Puzzle(id: UUID(), index: 4, pieceName: "piece4", locationPiece: CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%1000),y:Int(arc4random()%1000)), geo: .zero),
                                  Puzzle(id: UUID(), index: 5, pieceName: "piece5", locationPiece: CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%1000),y:Int(arc4random()%1000)), geo: .zero)]
    @State var lastTapLocation: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return Group {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    Image(item.pieceName)
                        .offset(self.getOffset(item.locationPiece))
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                                .updating(self.$dragState) { value, state, transaction in
                                    state = .dragging(translation: value.translation)
                                }
                                .onEnded { value in
                                    // get new location and stay piece on new position screen
                                    changeLocation(item_uuid: item.id.uuidString, newLoc: pieceSatte)
                                }
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    // try found location empty picture on screen
                                    let startLoc = value.startLocation
                                    let endLoc = value.location
                                    if abs(startLoc.x - endLoc.x) <= 740 && abs(startLoc.y - endLoc.y) <= 450 && item.pieceName.contains("piece4") {
                                        changeLocation(item_uuid: item.id.uuidString, newLoc: pieceSatte4)
                                    } else {
                                        self.changeLocation(item_uuid: item.id.uuidString, newLoc: value.location)
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                        .updating($dragState) { value, state, transaction in
                            state = .dragging(translation: value.translation)
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            let startLoc = value.startLocation
                            let endLoc = value.location
                            if abs(startLoc.x - endLoc.x) <= 10 && abs(startLoc.y - endLoc.y) <= 10 {
                            }
                        }
                        .onChanged { value in
                            self.lastTapLocation = value.startLocation
                        })
        }
    }
    
    func changeLocation(item_uuid: String, newLoc: CGPoint) {
        //get new location
        for i in 0..<items.count {
            if items[i].id.uuidString == item_uuid {
                items[i].locationPiece = newLoc
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func getOffset(_ originalOffset: CGPoint) -> CGSize {
        let xOffset = (-1 * (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2) + originalOffset.x)
        let yOffset = (-1 * (UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2) + originalOffset.y)
        
        return CGSize(width: xOffset, height: yOffset)
    }
}

// Check state drag
enum DragState {
    case inactive
    case pressing
    case dragging(translation: CGSize)
    
    var translation: CGSize {
        switch self {
        case .inactive, .pressing:
            return .zero
        case .dragging(let translation):
            return translation
        }
    }
    
    var isPressing: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .pressing, .dragging:
            return true
        case .inactive:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You posted a whole bunch of code with no comments in it. You need to explain what your logic is supposed to do and what you've done to try to debug it. If it were me I would calculate the Pythagorean distance between the center of the piece being dragged and it's target location. When that distance gets close enough you could highlight the piece and treat it as success if the user lets go.

Comment: @DuncanC  added comments, but I think Pythagorean not work here, because all pieces have randomizes coordinate when you show it's view